# NPM: Updating modules within modules

Tags: npm

In my NodeJS projects I use of course some external modules, those modules relies on other packages. Some of the developer maintaining those modules are very slow at updating the modules they use in their own project. Even when the issue is regarding security.

Is it possible to bump up a NPM modules within a modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `package.json` file within those npm packages you wish to update the dependencies for, but really this isn't an ideal solution. Any time an `npm install` is performed you'll lose those changes. Best to, if possible, fork the Git repos for those packages and make the changes yourself.